How to edit Opus comments?
Is there any tool that can edit Opus comments? In particular, I want to add multiple METADATA_BLOCK_PICTUREs to an Ogg/Opus file.

opusenc can't edit comments.
EasyTag corrupts Ogg files.
ffmpeg doesn't support duplicate fields.

All existing answers to my knowledge either only work on Ogg/Vorbis, require re-encoding the audio, or don't support multiple pictures.

I finally got a solution working using mutagen. There is no CLI, but fortunately it takes very little code to accomplish basic tasks. For example, a very dumb CLI that takes three arguments, file, key and value, can be written as follows:
import sys
import mutagen

f = mutagen.File(sys.argv[1])
f[sys.argv[2]] = sys.argv[3]
f.save()

This could be turned, rather easily, into a decent front-end. (In my case, I don't actually need a general purpose front-end and I was already using Python to write a metadata file to feed ffmpeg, which made the switch to mutagen fairly straight forward.)
Setting the same key multiple times is a little wonky:
f[key] = [value1, value2, ...]

...but it works; key will appear multiple times, once for each specified value.
There are also utilities to help turn images into appropriate VORBISCOMMENT blocks, though I didn't use them, as I'd already written my own version for my prior attempts to use ffmpeg.

I've been using opuscomment the past few months. Haven't had any problems with it, although it works differently than vorbiscomment despite its name. If you wanted to add multiple METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE labels, you would do:
# `-a` handles the file in append mode.

opuscomment myfile.ogg -a -t 'METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE=...' -t 'METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE=...'

...although you'd probably get an error due to the arguments' length, which should be a base64-encoded string containing the metadata's value in the correct size and order:

4 bytes specifying the picture type.
4 bytes specifying the MIME type length.
n bytes with the MIME type name.
4 bytes specifying the length of the description.
n bytes with the description.
4 bytes indicating the image width.
4 bytes indicating the image height.
4 bytes indicating color depth.
4 bytes indicating the number of colors used, if the image is an indexed-color one.
4 bytes specifying the length of the picture data in bytes.
n bytes of the picture data.

Having your tags in a text file, you could then do:
opuscomment -a -c mytags.txt myfile.ogg

You could also delete all of the previous METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE if something went wrong:
opuscomment -d METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE myfile.ogg

Keep in -d implies -a, and given that -a expects an EOF, you need to send it yourself (typically ^D/Ctrl+D) unless you're actually appending something with a here-document, from a file, a tag specified with -t etc.:
# delete picture tags and assign everything from mytags.txt
opuscomment -d METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE -c mytags.txt myfile.ogg

